# How to get unlimited height for stage in Konva and compability issue with IE / Firefox

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, konvajs

For my project I need to generate a konva page with a lot of nodes. User have to able to add new node and remove it. So far our productive data has around 8000 nodes. I work with angularJS and Konva. The pages must be work in Chrome, IE and Firefox. The codes look like this (modified because of company policy):

```
angular.module('testModule').controller('compabilityTestCtrl', [
function () {
    var compabilityTestCtrl = this;
    compabilityTestCtrl.stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: angular.element('<div>')[0],
        width: 800,
        height: 0
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer({});

    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 50,
        y: 25,
        width: 100,
        height: 50,
        fill: 'green',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });

    layer.add(rect);
    compabilityTestCtrl.stage.height(rect.attrs.y + 50);

    for (var i = 1; i < 436; i++) {
        var newRect = rect.clone({
            y: rect.attrs.y + (i * 75)
        });

        layer.add(newRect);
        compabilityTestCtrl.stage.height(newRect.attrs.y + 75);

        if (i == 435) {
            console.log("Stage height is: " + compabilityTestCtrl.stage.getHeight());
        }
    }

    compabilityTestCtrl.stage.add(layer);
    angular.element('#compabilityTestKonva').append(compabilityTestCtrl.stage.content);
}]);
```

The problem is following:
 1. As you can see, it can generate a node until a stage height of 32725px. If I add one more node (for-Loop to 437), the page will dissapeared (in Chrome). It can only generate until 436 nodes.
 2. In Firefox, for 436 nodes the page is not totally generated. It just show 3/4 part of them. If I switched to safe-mode, it showed all of them. More than 436 nodes, it also dissapeared like in Chrome.
 3. In IE, it just showed 1/4 of all nodes.

Questions:
Why I can not display all the pages in Firefox and IE?
Why the pages dissapeared if the stage getting bigger (in all browser), in this case.. more than 32725 px? Has Konva a limited height of stage?

I would be very happy for your suggestions.

I just wrote a fiddle, so you know what is actually the problem I have.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blown_eye/c8sd3s2t/2/)

In fiddle, it can generate up to 430 nodes (in Chrome), more than that I see only a blank page. In Firefox it ended on 353 nodes, and in IE it ended on 108 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas element is like an image.

32725px height is super-duper huge. It will use a lot of resources.

Try to make a stage as small as possible. It will be better to make it not bigger than screen size. You can add some type of scrolling into the stage so users can see all objects.

Comment: You're right. I commented this line: stage.height(stage.getHeight() + 75)., and let the height constant. And now it can generate more faster, even if I give more than 430 nodes. Do you have a suggestion, how to make it scrollable?

Comment: @blown.eye it depends on your app. There are a lot of ways to scroll.
You can make stage draggable, or you can draw a rectangle on the left side and implement it as scrollbar, so moving it will move a stage.

Comment: I tried to split it to many stage, as you can see on this JSFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/blown_eye/c8sd3s2t/10/). Do you think it's a good idea? Why I got an empty stage for the second stage?